# UITableView within a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

How can I use a [uitableview](/questions/tagged/uitableview) inside of a [uiviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/uiviewcontroller)? Below is an example of what I'm trying to do (except this is just the `UITableview` in my Storyboard):

[image: UITableView inside a UIViewController]

I've figured out that I need to add the delegate and data source to my header:

```
//MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

In my Implementation file, I've added the required methods:

```
//MyViewController.m

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FileCell"];

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *fileListAct = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fileListAct objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

The `delegate`, `datasource`, and `UITableView` are all hooked up in my Storyboard:

[image: UITableView Delegate and DataSource in Interface Builder Connections Outlet]

I can't get the TableView to load the content that I tell it to. It always comes up blank. Why won't the TableView fill with the content I tell it to in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do have to link the dataSource and delegate outlets from the tableview in storyboard to the view controller. This is not optional. This is why your table is blank, it is never calling your view controller's table view methods.  (You can prove this by setting breakpoints on them and seeing that they never get triggered.)  What sort of build errors are you getting?

Comment: I no longer get build errors, but when I attempt to interact with the table the app crashed. And is the cellForRowAtIndex method the right place to populate the table view?

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?  Set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions so you can find out what line it is crashing on too.

Comment: I connected the dataSource and delegate outlets to my ViewController (properly) and I no longer get build errors or crashes. When I set breakpoints at cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection, they are found but their content is never executed. Also, it never even steps into cellForRowAtIndexPath, this method is just ignored. Why is this happening?

Comment: If those methods aren't being called, it's because the delegate/dataSource connections are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning any valid value.
See the `return;` without any numeric value to return?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return; // it should be return 15; or return self.datasource.count;
  NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an IBOutlet for YourTableView, then connect TableView to YourTableView

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `UITableViewDelegate` method `numberOfRowsInSection`. This one does not return an `NSInteger` number of rows. This example can help:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return theNumberOfRowsForYourTable; // <-- not just return;
}
```