# How to put a Table View Controller into a Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm starting out with learning Table Views. My applications uses a Tab Bar Controller and all the tabs are simple views. I want to add another tab, and put a Table View inside of it..how do i do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: My question here may help, and although it doesn't use a TabBar Controller the same concept can be applied: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324744/table-view-within-a-normal-ios-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

If I want to add another view controller to a tab bar controller, I usually do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *items = [tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
MyTableViewController *c = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
[items addObject:c];
[c release];
tabBarController.viewControllers = items;
[items release];
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have created the tab bar controller.  If it was designed in IB, then drag another tab bar item over to the main window. I then embed a view controller within the tab bar and assign it to the tableview class in question.  The .h file for the class will need to be written:

```
@interface myClass : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

The other method that Apple uses when you first set up a basic tab bar app, handles it programmatically with the app delegate. See:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

for the relevant code.

Comment: I believe it would be `@interface myClass : UIViewController` or TabView Controller. user1640496 wants to add a TableView not a TableViewController.